# Optimizing memory for writes

Tags: c++, performance, x86, x86-64, memory-optimization

I am working on a sorting algorithm that iterates over a bunch of integers and puts them into buckets.

The exact type of the buckets is a custom data structure similar to `std::vector`. As you can imagine, there is a snippet similar to this one, for the case that there is already enough memory allocated in the bucket to write the element I'm adding:

```
*_end = _new_value; // LINE 1
++_end; // Line 2
```

I discovered in vtune optimizer that that LINE 1 accounts for about 1/3 of the runtime of my algorithm. I was curious if I could do better, so I started trying some stuff.

My workstation is Linux and I usually compile with gcc. Our software has to support other compilers and systems, too, but Linux-only optimizations are considered OK since we "suggest" users use Linux.

First I simply added a look-ahead to my the loop from which the above snippet is called. Looking ahead `buffer_size` iterations, it got the result from:

```
int * Bucket::get_end() {
    __builtin_prefetch(_end, 1); // Line 3
    return _end++; // Line 4
}
```

And it stored these results in a buffer similar to the following `buffer`:

```
using delayed_write = std::pair<int, int*>; // Line 5
std::array<delayed_write, buffer_size> buffer; // Line 6
```

I'd run the equivalent of:

```
*(buffer[i + buffer_size].second) = buffer[i + buffer_size].first;
```

This eliminated the bottleneck like I saw at line 2 in vtune, but the algorithm was slower overall. (I tried 4 and 8 as `buffer_size`).

I tried a few other things. In particular, I did some pretty complex stuff where I totally batched 4 or 8 integers at a time and did each step on all of them at once. I wrote code to try to look ahead to see if reallocation will be necessary; if not, I cleverly wrote some loops that avoided any data dependencies across steps of the loop. Of course all this complexity predictably made the algorithm *much* slower. :)

It's possible it simply can't be made faster, but I feel intuitively there should be some way to exploit that there is no data dependency on line 2's write until after the loop is over so that there's no need to wait for the likely cache miss there to be resolved.

My understanding is that a cache miss is very high-latency, but I sort of wonder why the CPU can't keep going and leave the writes in a buffer to handle asynchronously.

It'd be really cool if there were e.g. a way to promise that I'm not going to read that memory until I call some synchronization function to commit all of the writes so far.

Do you think in fact that I'm filling up the write buffer? (In which case there is no solution?)

If not, does anyone know of any ways to exploit the fact that the write will not be read until after the hot loop?

Comment: It might be a good thing that you don't need many operations beyond adding things to buckets. Just to offer a possible alternative interpretation.

Comment: Based on the fact you've mentioned vtune, I assume you're on x86. You can try a  non-temporal store [`_mm_stream_si32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_stream_si32&expand=5673). Also keep in mind, x86 memory access works in 64-byte lines, so when writing 4 bytes, 64 bytes need to be loaded, updated and written back. The buffers for doing that (LFBs) are limited to 10..12 on modern x86's.

Comment: @rustyx: NT stores are only good if you write a fully 64-byte aligned cache-line as a group.  You're unlikely to get that when scattering data into buckets for Radix or BucketSort, or any similar pattern.  See [Why is \`\_mm\_stream\_si128\` much slower than \`\_mm\_storeu\_si128\` on Skylake-Xeon when writing parts of 2 cache lines? But less effect on Haswell](//stackoverflow.com/q/57420025)

Comment: In theory NT stores are exactly what the OP wants: a promise that store-reordering is fine until `sfence`.  But in practice there are only a dozen LFBs on Skylake, used for write-combining buffers, but also data transfers between L1d <-> L2 cache also need an LFB.  So when a cache-miss load needs to allocate an LFB, it can easily flush a partially-written WC buffer.  The store buffer + L1d cache should already be good at absorbing multiple output streams of cached stores, better than NT stores.  (Especially if they don't all alias the same cache way).

Comment: is `_new_value` slow to calculate?  Perf counters often "blame" the instruction waiting for something that's not ready yet, instead of the instruction that's slow to produce it.

Comment: correction, alias the same cache *set* is what I meant to say.  (For L1d on Intel, that means the cache-line address modulo 4k is the same.)  So if you had 10 output arrays that were all page-aligned (or aligned the same relative to a page, like glibc malloc/new does for large allocations), and the output position in each array was the same (i.e. they all move in lockstep) that would be a problem.

Comment: @Peter _new_value is trivial to calculate, at least in this particular benchmark. Computing the particular bucket's index is not trivial, but not real hard either. I don't expect it usually involves a cache miss, e.g.

Comment: I will look into _mm_stream_si32, but as you say, it might not help. Does anyone have a source for where these sorts of functions are even listed and documented?

Comment: Ultimately, the better you can utilize cache lines, the faster your code will be. Data locality is key.